# Colour background by variable and box variable titles ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add outline boxes to Variable labels and colour background per variable.

I have tried this:

```
data<- tibble::tibble(
  Sample = c("1","2","3","4"),
  value = c(1.5, 1.3, -1.2, -0.6),
  Group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"))

ggplot(data, aes(x=Sample, y=value, fill=data$Group) )+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.8,colour="black")+
  theme_classic()+
  ggtitle("general title")+
  annotate("text", x = 1.5, y=2, label= "This is Group1", fontface =2)+
  annotate("text", x = 3.5, y=2, label= "This is Group2",fontface =2)+
  geom_rect(aes(fill = Group), xmin = 2.5, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.3)
```

And I would like the background to be under the Barnhart and labels boxed.
[image]

Comment: Change `annotate("text"...` to `annotate("label"...` for a rounded box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

data<- tibble::tibble(
  Sample = c("1","2","3","4"),
  value = c(1.5, 1.3, -1.2, -0.6),
  Group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"))

# with some more formatting: square corners, more padding and background fill:

ggplot(data, aes(x=Sample, y=value, fill = Group) )+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.8,colour="black")+
  theme_classic()+
  ggtitle("general title")+
  annotate("label", x = 1.5, y=2, label.r = unit(0, "lines"), label.padding = unit(0.5, "lines"), fill = "#F8766D", label= "This is Group1", fontface =2)+
  annotate("label", x = 3.5, y=2, , label.r = unit(0, "lines"), label.padding = unit(0.5, "lines"),fill = "#00BFC4", label= "This is Group2",fontface =2)+
  geom_rect(aes(fill = Group), xmin = 2.5, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.1)
```

Gives you:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the label, do you know about the background issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Peter !